# How to display name using ID from database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i want to display name from database using ID i mean using `row`

i tried to use this but it's not working....

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Bhawanku","members");
// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id='$id' ");
}
?>
```

Comment: No one helped me there ..... :( :(

Comment: **DO NOT** repost the same question 30 minutes later.  If you didn't get the help you needed, it's because your question is unclear.  Voting to close this one...  **You got lots of help** on that question, but you keep repeating the vague question "how to get display id using row?"  What does that mean?  Add **useful** comments to answers, and people will try and help.

Comment: Is Bhawanku your password?

Answer (score 0):

First Your objective is unclear . You want to get name (means what ? Its. A column on table.  ) .  If you want to get values from table by id.  Why you need two queries.   One enough for your answer
SELECT columnname from admin where id=1

This query returns the table row that have primary key you are used in where

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) ;
$name=$row['columnname']; // your answer